# How to display every element in json_encode result into PHP tabular

Tags: php, jquery, json

I would like to display every element in result of json_encode into tabular format in PHP (See below). In this case, the jQuery code (in header section) and PHP code (in body section) are in the same PHP page.

Can anyone help me?

```
+-------+-------+
|fruit  |price  |
+-------+-------+
|apple  |1.2    |
+-------+-------+
|pear   |1.5    |
+-------+-------+
|orange |1.0    |
+-------+-------+
```

Result of test.php:

```
[{"fruit":"apple","price":1.2},{"fruit":"pear","price":1.5},{"fruit":"orange","price":1.0}]
```

The above code is result of test.php by using json_encode().

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   dataType:"Json",
                   url: "test.php",
                   success: function(result){


                   }
                 });
            });
```

Comment: you have only specified your need, not your question. what hinders you to write the code exactly? Otherwise this is hard to answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var json_array = '';
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"Json",
    url: "test.php",
    success: function(result){
        // Parse JSON
        var array_json = $.parseJSON(array_json);
        // We add each row in the table
        $.each(array_json, function(){
            $('#results').append('<tr><td>' + this.fruit + '</td><td>' + this.price + '</td></tr>');
        });
    }
});
```

});

With the following HTML :

```
<table id="results">
    <tr>
        <th>Fruit</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

(Change the ID depending on your HTML structure)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some HTML

```
<table id="fruits">
  <tr>
    <td>Fruit</td>
    <td>Price</td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Your jQuery

```
success: function(result){
  var t = $("table#fruits");
  $.each(result, function(i, fruit){
    t.append('<tr><td>' + fruit.fruit + '</td><td>' + fruit.price + '</td></tr>');
  });
}
```

See it working here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8aXw/)